# Tried to compile valkyrie(GUI for valgrind) and it throws an error:

Tags: c, qt, valgrind

Tried to compile valkyrie(valgrind GUI) and it throws an error. 
Steps:

1. Download valkyrie 2.0.0 from valgrind website
2. After untar I followed the instructions under INSTALL file:
3. stillstoned@stillstoned ~/Downloads/valkyrie-2.0.0/src $ qmake-qt4 PREFIX=/opt

> ```
> stillstoned@stillstoned ~/Downloads/valkyrie-2.0.0/src $ make
> compiling objects/tool_object.cpp
>
>
> objects/tool_object.cpp: In member function ‘bool ToolObject::startProcess(QStringList)’:
>
> objects/tool_object.cpp:391:42: error: ‘usleep’ was not declared in this scope
>        usleep( WAIT_VG_START_SLEEP * 1000 );
>                                           ^
>
> objects/tool_object.cpp: In member function ‘void ToolObject::stopProcess()’:
>
> objects/tool_object.cpp:474:42: error: ‘usleep’ was not declared in this scope
>              usleep( 1000 * sleepDuration );
>                                           ^
> make: *** [Makefile:627: obj/tool_object.o] Error 1
> stillstoned@stillstoned ~/Downloads/valkyrie-2.0.0/src $
> ```

Do you have any idea on this?
Thanks!!! I appreciate all your answers.

Comment: Do you really need to build yourself? What's wrong with the version that comes with the OS? It's at 2.0.0 if you're on Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo apt install valkyrie`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue on a standard RHEL 7.1 (3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64) system.  Since this system doesn't have RH subscription to allow using yum, I had to resort to downloading the .bz2 and building it myself.  Here's how I worked around the compiler errors.

Issue #1: objects/tool_object.cpp:392:42: error: ?usleep? was not declared in this scope.
Fix #1: Add `#include <unistd.h>` to that source

Issue #2: utils/vk_config.cpp:125:25: error: ?getuid? was not declared in this scope
Fix #2: Add `#include <unistd.h>` and `#include <sys/types.h>` to the source.

Issue #3: utils/vk_utils.cpp:54:83: error: ?getpid? was not declared in this scope.
Fix #3: Add `#include <unistd.h>` and `#include <sys/types.h>` to the source.

With those fixes in place I followed the steps in the "INSTALL" file and now Valkyrie (v2.0.0) + Valgrind (v3.12.0) are working fine together.

Comment: On RHEL 7.4 I found that adding unistd.h only to each of the three files was sufficient.